# i need to get the second td span value based on tr id how can i get that?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i need to get the second td span value based on tr id

`

```
            <table><tr id="1">
            <td style="width:150px;"><span id="1">C </span></td>
            <td><span style="width:800px;">hello world</span></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="1" onclick="KeywordText(1);" value="1"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="2">
            <td style="width:150px;"><span id="2">Dot Net </span></td>
            <td><span style="width:800px;">Dot Net,java,cobol,hai,Dot Net,java,cobol,hai,Dot Net,java,cobol,hai,Dot Net,java,cobol,hai</span></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="2" onclick="KeywordText(2);" value="2"></td>
            </tr></table>
```

Comment: You need to get the second td that has a span, or just the span in the second td ?

Comment: You shouldn use the same id on more then one object... your tr and span object have the same id in your example

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This assumes you want the second span

JavaScript:

```
var row = document.getElementById("rowId");
var spans = row.getElementsByTagName("span");
var secondSpan = spans[1];
```

jQuery:

```
var secondSpan = $("#rowId span:eq(1)");
```

It you want the span inside the second table cell

JavaScript:

```
var row = document.getElementById("rowId");
var cells = row.getElementsByTagName("td");
var spans = cells.getElementsByTagName("span");
var secondSpan = spans[0];
```

or with querySelector

```
var span = document.getElementById("rowId").querySelector("td + td > span");
```

jQuery:

```
var secondSpan = $("#rowId td:eq(1) span");
```

And spans do not have a value, you either what its html or its text.

JavaScript:

```
var text = secondSpan.innerHTML;
```

jQuery:

```
var text = secondSpan.html();  // or secondSpan.text();
```

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery:

```
 var getvalue=$(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(1) span').val();
 alert(getvalue);
```

Comment: eq is 0 based.For second td it is 1,

Answer (score 0):

```
function KeywordText(id) {
  var td = document.getElementById(id).cells[1];

  console.log(td.firstChild.innerHTML); // "hello word" if id == 1
}
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/n2t4Z/

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking, you can do it like this:

```
getSpanValueByRowId(1);

function getSpanValueByRowId(rowID) {
    var row = document.getElementById(rowID);
    var cells = row.getElementsByTagName("td");

    var span = cells[1].getElementsByTagName("span")[0];

    return span.innerText;
}
```

Although you could use jQuery to get it, it would look like this:

```
function getSpanValueByjQuery(rowID){
    return $("#"+rowID + " td:nth-child(2) span").text();
}
```